# swing-replacing components on GridBagLayout

Tags: java, image, swing, jbutton, gridbaglayout

I searched for hours for an answer,tried every method I know about and didnt find an answer.
I'm working on eclipse, my class is extending JFrame and im trying to replace two components that I added to the frame(using gridbaglayout).
 
When I'm removing the first one,I can't get to add the second one to where the first one was.
 
The components are `JButton` with images.
how do I get to add and remove components wherever I want? (already tried using GridBagConstraints to add it to the place I just removed a component from)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After that I would recommend posting [mcve] to show what you tried and what fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround you could add to your main panel (using GridbagLayout) inherited panels with the buttons in it. Then when you want to replace these buttons (or whatever component) you dont replace them on main panel. You replace them in the inherited panels. Since you are not giving us code, a kind of pseudocode would be like:

```
JButton myBtn = new JButton(); //Theinitial button
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout()); //main panel
JPanel inheritedPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout())//borderlayout to fill the entire panel.
inheritedPanel.add(myBtn,BorderLayout.CENTER);
mainPanel.add(inheritedPanel, myConstraints);

JButton replacementBtn = new JButton;
inheritedPanel.remove(myBtn);
inheritedPanel.add(replacementBtn);
inheritedPanel.repaint();
inheritedPanel.revalidate();
```

Comment: @Orel Vaknin i am glad that i helped you.

Answer (score 0):

> The components are JButton with images.

Just replace the image by using the `setIcon(...)` method.

Comment: Then you logic is wrong? You have been asked for a [mcve] to demonstrate the problem. Since you haven't posted one, you are on your own. So as a simple test you create a frame with two buttons. The first buttons shows text (because we don't have access to your images). Then the second button will change the text of the first button. Once you get that working. Then you understand the concept of changing a property of a given component. Then you try it with images. The entire "MCVE" will be about 20 lines of code. If you don't have to the time to create one, then we can't help.